# All of character set Contains Digits?

Tags: character

American Standard Code Of Information Interchange

Unicode

or more character set Contains  Digits? Example:1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking which character sets contain digits, the answers are yes, yes and yes.

ASCII has the digits from `0` thru `9` at code points `0x30` thru `0x39`.

So do ISO 10646 and Unicode, which share the same character encodings in the low range at least. They are also at code points `0x30/U+30` thru `0x39/U+39` (since the lower 128 characters are equivalent to ASCII).

As for the final paragraph asking if there are *other* character set that contain digits, I can think of at least *one* off the top of my head, EBCDIC. These are at code points `0xf0` thru `0xf9`.

No doubt there are other encoding schemes that include digits as well, given their usefulness.